# C++: vector< set<string> > initialization by function

Tags: c++, string, vector, initialization, set

In C++, I would like to initialize a vector of sets of strings by:

```
string border(getBorder());
vector<string> W(_h_,border+"_"+border);
vector< set<string> > W_f(_h_,getNgrams(&W[0]));
```

where:

```
set<string> getNgrams(string word){ ... }
```

and:

```
string getBorder(){ ... }
```

The error message reads:

```
conversion from 'std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*' to non-scalar type 'std::string' requested
```

Comment: Which line is the error message referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`W[0]` Results in a `std::string`, hence `&W[0]` is a pointer to string and you have `getNgrams(std::string)` not `getNgrams(std::string*)`, hence the compiler complains about the conversion from `std::string*` to `std::string`

Comment: I had an error before using W[0], but now it works. I there was another reason why W[0] did not work before...

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign an `std::string*` to an `std::string` here:

```
vector< set<string> > W_f(_h_,getNgrams(&W[0]));
```

`&W[0]` is an `std::string*`, but `getNgrams` expects an `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

```
set<string> getNgrams(string word){ ... }
```

your `getNgrams` function takes a `string` but you're passing in a `string*` here:

```
vector<string> W(_h_,border+"_"+border);
vector< set<string> > W_f(_h_,getNgrams(&W[0])); // look at the argument being passed.
```

`w` is a `vector<string>`, `w[0]` therefore is a `string`, and you're passing `&w[0]` which is a `string*`

Answer (score 1):

On this line:

```
vector< set<string> > W_f(_h_,getNgrams(&W[0]));
```

you get the address of `W[0]` using the `&` operator. The type of `W[0]` is `std::string` and the type of the address is std::string* (or more specifically, what you see in the error message). You then pass that pointer to the function `getNgrams` which expects a string instead of a pointer.

Simply remove the `&` operator to fix. You may wish to use a const reference instead though, to avoid copying the string:

```
set<string> getNgrams(const string& word)
```